# How to vertically join the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have a table like this:

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100), ParentID INT)
INSERT INTO @Nodes VALUES 
(1, 'Test', NULL),
(2, 'Test', 1),
(3, 'Test', 2),
(5, 'Test', 3),
(6, 'Test', 1)
```

Now I would like to query that table, retrieving node with ID 3 and all parent nodes. ParentID would be a foreign key to the same table's ID column. The number of possible parent nodes is infinite. Result would be this:

```
ID  Name    ParentID
1   Test    NULL
2   Test    1
3   Test    2
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  a [recursive common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH Nodes 
AS(
  SELECT 1 AS relationLevel, child.*
  FROM  @Nodes child
  WHERE child.ID = 3

  UNION ALL

  SELECT relationLevel+1, parent.*
  FROM Nodes nextOne
  INNER JOIN  @Nodes parent ON parent.ID = nextOne.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM Nodes order by ID
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23257/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ID INT=3
;with cte as(
select ID,Name,ParentID FROM @Nodes WHERE ID=@ID
UNION ALL
SELECT n.ID,n.Name,n.ParentID FROM cte inner join @Nodes n on cte.ParentID= n.ID
)
SELECT ID,Name,ParentID FROM cte
ORDER BY ParentID
```